# how to install brew forumlae simultaneously?

Tags: homebrew, async

I tried this, I'll keep the list short:

```bash
IFS=$'\n'

pkgs=(
  go
  gcc
  make
  node
) 

installPkgs() {
   brew install $1
}

export -f installPkgs

parallel -j 0 installPkgs ::: ${pkgs[@]}
```

This didn't work as when I typed `node` I got 'command not found'.

I know you can do:

```
brew install \
  go         \
  gcc        \
  make       \
  node
```

But this a sequential install, is it possible to do a simultaneous or async install?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to do a simultaneous or async install

I don't think so. Installations *are* inherently sequential problems, if you think about it – you're modifying one global state, and the operations done while doing that aren't atomic nor easily synchronized.

Also, installations are almost completely IO bound. You'd be waiting on storage in parallel, which is not significantly faster at all.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, the whole idea is flawed as I was going for speed, and seems it would break things.